# Subtract a value from previous cell with sum and offset function

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have a column with different values.

In this column, I want to subtract the value in A1 from the value in A2, the value in A3 from A4 and so on. I then want the result to show in the B column.

[image]

I found that this can be accomplished with SUM and OFFSET.

Can someone show me how exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No SUM or OFFSET needed. Just put nothing in B1 and '=A2-A1' in B2. Next, select B1 *and* B2. Then copy-paste down (drag tge black square at the lower right of your selection or just select copy from the menu and select the target area an click paste).

The copy-paste copies the altering cell with nothing and the cell with the formula down below as far as you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth,
the formula in **B2** may also be set to be `=SUM(OFFSET(B2,-1,-1,2,1))`
- which might come in handy if you (for some reason) need to have it reference no other cells than itself.

*The numbers in `OFFSET()` says this:  -1,-1 - 'move up and left 1 step each', 2,1 - 'include two rows and one colum'... and then you have `SUM()` on these cells as OFFSET() is inside its parenthesis.*